# Show local asymptotic distribution of the Maximum Likelihood estimator

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, local-statistics

from a problem set I have the following exercise:

> Let $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ be iid with $X_1 \sim N(\theta, 1)$, where $\theta \geq 0$. The ML estimator of $\theta$ is $\hat{\theta}_n = \max (\bar{X}_n, 0) $. Let $\theta_n=\theta+h / \sqrt{n}$. (a) Show that if $\theta \neq 0$, then $\sqrt{n}\left(\hat{\theta}_n-\theta_n\right) \underset{\theta_n}{\stackrel{d}{\longrightarrow}} N(0,1)$. That is, the limiting distribution does not depend on $h$.

My answer to this question was:
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{n}\left(\hat{\theta}_n-\theta_n\right) &= \sqrt{n}\left(\hat{\theta}_n-\theta + \frac{h}{\sqrt{n}}\right) = \sqrt{n}\left(\hat{\theta}_n-\theta \right) - h \stackrel{d}{\longrightarrow} N(0, 1) - h = N(-h,1)
\end{align*}

In the last equality before the arrow, I used the fact that sample mean is normally distributed and use the Delta Method for the function $\max(\bar{X}_{n},0)$ and the Slutksy's theorem.

Why is it wrong?
If possible can someone, intuitively, explain the concept of local asymptotics?

Comment: How did you determine that $\sqrt{n}\left(\hat{\theta}_n-\theta \right)  \stackrel{d}{\longrightarrow} N(0, 1) $?

Comment: I used the Central Limit Theorem on $\bar{X}_{n}$ and the Delta Method on the function $g(\bar{X}_{n}) = max(\bar{X}_{n}, 0)$. I know I can use the Delta Method because function  $g(\bar{X}_{n})$ is differentiable  at $\theta$ given that $\theta > 0$

Comment: Unfortunately, the lack of differentiability at $0$ is a problem.   (Notice that $\bar X_n$ can be zero or negative.) That's the entire point of this exercise.